# How can I stop Blender from rendering the 3D scene instead of my video?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

I am trying to render a video in the video editor of Blender 2.83b. However, when trying to render it, Blender just renders a view of the default cube instead. I have never interacted with the 3D scene in this project and I just want to render the video I made. How can I get it to render the correct thing?

Comment: I removed the camera from the 3D scene, and now I am notified that there is no camera to render from at all. So it appears there is no camera set to capture the video, if that's how it works? In that case, how do I add a camera for rendering to the video?

Comment: Hi. Please don't use the comments to expand the scope of your questions or to add new information. Please use the edit link below your question to add the additional infos to the original text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to check the Sequencer tag. I wasn't able to find it from other answers originally as it has moved in the new 2.8 UI.

[image: UI Screenshot]